# Where is email delivered if the domain on a shared IP has A record but does not have MX records?

Tags: email, mx-record, address

Some say that an mail server can deliver email to the IP address where the domain is pointed to by A record even if the domain does not have corresponding MX records, though it is not recommended.

However, from my experience, the email will not be delivered on the shared server without MX records at all.

So, why won't it be delivered?

Is it connected with the shared IP address or is the email rejected by spam filters as the domain does not have proper records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an MX record does not exist, the SMTP related RFC's specify a "Fallback to A record" mechanism. So, in the absence of MX records an SMTP server may attempt to deliver email to the A record for the domain. In most cases, the email will be rejected unless there happens to be an authoritative SMTP server at the A record.